# GemFire 8.2.0 cluster using static server list in cache.xml

Tags: java, xml, gemfire

How can I make a GemFire 8.2.0 P2P cluster of GemFire servers using only statically defined server list in the `cache.xml` configuration file?

I cannot use multicast.  I do not want to use the separate locator process.

My `cache.xml` for server nodes

```xml
<!DOCTYPE cache PUBLIC
"-//GemStone Systems, Inc.//GemFire Declarative Caching 8.0//EN"
"http://www.gemstone.com/dtd/cache8_0.dtd">
<cache>
  <cache-server port="40404" />
  <pool name="serverPool">
      <server host="10.0.0.192" port="40404" />
      <server host="10.0.0.193" port="40404" />
  </pool>
</cache>
```

I have read in the documentation that I can have a static list of servers in the pool,   I see on the client side, this style of configuration works. and my clients connect to the list of servers.
but GemFire server / peer to peer clustering using only static cluster configuration is not working for me.

I am now using 

`serverCache = new CacheFactory().set("cache-xml-file", "server-cache.xml").set("mcast-port", "0")
                .set("start-locator","localhost[13489]").set("locators", "localhost[13489]").create();`

in the logs of this jmv i see

```
[info 2016/02/08 15:47:34.922 UTC  tid=0x1] Starting peer location for Distribution Locator on localhost/127.0.0.1[13489]

[info 2016/02/08 15:47:34.925 UTC  tid=0x1] Starting Distribution Locator on localhost/127.0.0.1[13489]

[info 2016/02/08 15:47:48.093 UTC  tid=0x1] Starting server location for Distribution Locator on localhost/127.0.0.1[13489]
```

on a 2nd box I use

`serverCache = new CacheFactory().set("cache-xml-file", "server-cache.xml").set("mcast-port", "0").set("locators", "IP-of-1stbox[13489]").create();`

`com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a Locator service.  Operation either timed out or Locator does not exist.  Configured list of locators is "[ip-of-1stbox(null)<v0>:13489]".
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TCPGOSSIP.sendGetMembersRequest(TCPGOSSIP.java:222)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.PingSender.run(PingSender.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "main" com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a Locator service.  Operation either timed out or Locator does not exist.  Configured list of locators is "[54.173.123.102(null)<v0>:13489]".
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TCPGOSSIP.sendGetMembersRequest(TCPGOSSIP.java:222)
    at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.PingSender.run(PingSender.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

I have port 13489 open

I can see

`Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:13489      :::*                        LISTEN      5137/java
tcp        0      0 :::40404                    :::*                        LISTEN      5137/java
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.0.193:21145     :::*                        LISTEN      5137/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.0.193:65148     :::*                        LISTEN      5137/java
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               -
udp        0      0 10.0.0.193:123              0.0.0.0:*                               -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123               0.0.0.0:*                               -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123                 0.0.0.0:*                               -
udp        0      0 ::ffff:10.0.0.193:2300      :::*                                    5137/java`

port 13489  is in use on the first box

when i did get them connected i found this

`[warn 2016/02/08 16:38:12.688 UTC <locator request thread[1]> tid=0x20] Expected one of these: [class com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.locator.LocatorListRequest, class com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.JmxManagerLocatorRequest, class com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.locator.ClientReplacementRequest, class com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.locator.QueueConnectionRequest, class com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.GossipData, class com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.locator.ClientConnectionRequest, class com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.locator.LocatorStatusRequest, class com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.client.internal.locator.GetAllServersRequest] but received ConfigurationRequest for groups :
 cluster[cluster]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mixup in the `cache.xml`. You will need two sets of cache.xml, one for the server and one for the client. On the server `cache.xml`, you define the port on which the server will listen for client communication, defines your regions etc. Something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cache
    xmlns="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache/cache-8.1.xsd"
    version="8.1">
<cache-server port="40404" />
<region name="MyRegion" refid="PARTITION" />
</cache>
```

To start an embedded locator and point the server to other running servers in the system, you can do

```
CacheFactory cf = new CacheFactory();
cf.set("cache-xml-file", "server-cache1.xml");
cf.set("mcast-port", "0");
cf.set("start-locator", "12345");
cf.set("locators","localhost[12345],localhost[6789]");
```

In a second process, use the exact same `locators` property, and use `6789` as the `start-locator` port.

For the client cache.xml, you define a connection pool and provide it with a list of running servers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<client-cache
    xmlns="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache/cache-8.1.xsd"
    version="8.1">
<pool name="serverPool">
  <server host="localhost" port="40404" />
  <server host="localhost" port="40405" />
</pool>
<region name="MyRegion" refid="CACHING_PROXY"/>
</client-cache>
```

For your client application, you should create a `ClientCache` using the above cache.xml like so:

```
ClientCacheFactory ccf = new ClientCacheFactory();
ccf.set("cache-xml-file", "client.xml");
ClientCache clientCache = ccf.create();
Region r = clientCache.getRegion("MyRegion");
r.put("1", "one");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start a locator in an embedded mode (i.e. within the GemFire Server process by using the `start-locator` gemfire property.

One way to do this is:

1. put `start-locator=address1[port1]` in gemfire.properties file.
2. start the server using

   gfsh>start server --name=server1 --properties-file=/path/to/gemfire.properties
3. Start the second server by pointing it to the locator port in the first server:

   gfsh>start server --name=server2 --locators=address1[port1]

Comment: so are you saying,  I have to use the locator.  and that in fact it is not possible to form a GemFire cluster using only static cache.xml configuration of server lists ?    so my only choice if multi cast is not an option,  it to use the "locator" process.   I my homogenizes setup I would start and embedded locator in every GemFire server i create,  and have a list of locators in the cache.xml file,   thanks

Comment: All locators must be configured with the same list you use to configure the other distributed system members.

Comment: Note: Provide a server list or locator list, but not both.  so it should be possible to make a GemFire peer to peer  cluster via xml only

Comment: Yes, you will have to use an embedded locator. However the list of locators should be in gemfire.properties file (or on the `gfsh` command).

Only while configuring the clients the locator should show in cache.xml. Please refer to [Setting up Client Server System](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/topologies_and_comm/cs_configuration/setting_up_a_client_server_system.html) for more information.

Comment: hi Swapnil,  I have update the main Question,  as i am still having config issues.  any help would be great